# Java, access directory with relative path causes problems between different environments

Tags: java, path

In between environments(local and remote Jenkins build) i have different paths to reach the same directory:
Local:

```
product/version/src/main/
```

Jenkins build:

```
  ../../product/version/src/main/
```

The project structure is as follows:

```
Product
---Module
      src/main/java/com.product.core.DirFetcher.class
---Version
      src/main
```

And the way i retrieve it(locally) is like this(from the DirFetcher class):

```
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> paths = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("product/version/src/main/"))) {
```

This goes fine locally but throws an exception on Jenkins env.

I cant figure out why this is happening as the path is relative and the project structure is of course the same for both cases.
Is there a way to reach that directoy programmatically without doing any string transformation based on the current environment?

Comment: where that directory is located respect the caller class?

Comment: @Frighi i have modified the question, sorry, it was indeed quite unclear